# Splunk Brute Force Alerts showing only unknown

Tags: splunk

So we had some external contractors setup our splunk instances for us, and one of the things they setup for us was a Brute Force Alert email.
It seems to be based on the following query,

```
| tstats summariesonly=t allow_old_summaries=t count from datamodel=Authentication by Authentication.action, Authentication.src 
| rename Authentication.src as source, Authentication.action as action 
| chart last(count) over source by action 
| where success>0 and failure>20 
| sort -failure 
| rename failure as failures 
| fields - success, unknown
```

But all the report is showing me is that the source is unknown.

how can i find out what might be creating these "alerts" ?

Answer (score 1):

The Authentication data model uses "unknown" when a required field has no value or is not present.

Make sure your authentication events are CIM-compliant.  Add field aliases, evals, or extractions as necessary to populate the data model's `src` field.